# animateToRegion on onPress of Touchable Component in MapView

Tags: react-native, react-native-maps

In every item there is latitude and longitude stored in Redux. My goal is when I press it, it will navigate to it's coordinates or the latitude and longitude.

Here are my codes:

```
onPressAnimateToRegion = () => {
    const {latitude, longitude} = this.props.eventsState;
    this.map.animateToRegion({
        latitude,
        longitude,
        latitudeDelta: this.state.focusedLocation.latitudeDelta,
        longitudeDelta: this.state.focusedLocation.longitudeDelta
    })
}

            <Animated.FlatList
                horizontal
                scrollEventThrottle={1}
                // pagingEnabled={true}
                showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
                snapToInterval={SNAP_INTERVAL}
                style={styles.scrollView}
                contentContainerStyle={styles.endPadding}
                data={this.props.eventsState}
                keyExtractor={item => item.id}
                renderItem={(itemData) => (
                    <View style={styles.event}>
                        <View style={styles.touchable}>
                            <TouchableCmp 
                                onPress={this.onPressAnimateToRegion}
                                useForeground
                            >
                                <View>
                                    <ImageBackground source={{uri: itemData.item.imageUrl}} style={styles.image}>
                                        <View style={styles.textContainer}>
                                            <Text numberOfLines={1} style={styles.title}>{itemData.item.title}</Text>
                                            <Text numberOfLines={2} style={styles.description}>{itemData.item.description}</Text>
                                        </View>
                                    </ImageBackground>
                                </View>
                            </TouchableCmp>
                        </View>
                    </View>
                )}
            />
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you please add your map code as well as `onPressAnimateToRegion` method code?

Comment: There you go. Thanks

Comment: Can you please add <map> HTML code as well? I think you had given region value in <map>.

Comment: This is already done. Instead, help me on my next question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59046836/using-same-animation-in-marker-when-i-press-onpress